# I dont know how to run this

Tags: python, string, variables, input

I need to write this code for a person to enter a color or flavor in the input, no matter if it is in upper or lower case. For that I wrote a string with the different ways to write the colors. But it always appears false when I put a color or flavor regardless of whether I put it in lowercase or uppercase. How do I get TRUE to show up?

```
class class_apple:
    color = ""
    flavor = ""

Apple = class_apple()

Colors = "Red" and "red" and "RED"
Flavors = "Sweet" and "sweet" and "SWEET"

def Apple_color():
    Apple.color = input("Insert the color of the apple: ")
    if Apple.color == Colors:
        print("TRUE")
    else:
        print("FALSE")
```

[LOOK THIS PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebq6s.png)

Comment: Do copy the code in the image as code in your question rather than attaching an image

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the intro tour.    It's not clear where you have a problem or what you want for a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you should store all the colors to a `list`, and just `and` like that. And you should also learn this from scratch how to define a class, etc

```
class class_apple:
    color = ""
    flavor = ""

Apple = class_apple()

Colors = ["Red", "red", "RED"]
Flavors = ["Sweet", "sweet", "SWEET"]

def Apple_color():
    Apple.color = input("Insert the color of the apple: ")
    if Apple.color in Colors:
        print("TRUE")
    else:
        print("FALSE")
```

But I recommend to use `lower` to string object:

```
class class_apple:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = ""
        self.flavor = ""

Apple = class_apple()

Colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]
Flavors = ["sweet", "spicy"]

def Apple_color():
    Apple.color = input("Insert the color of the apple: ")
    if Apple.color.lower() in Colors:
        print("TRUE")
    else:
        print("FALSE")
```